# Error al acceder a API REST en PHP desde Android

Tags: php, android

Estoy intentando hacer que me cargue datos de la base de datos MySQL a través de un API REST en PHP a Android, pero me sale **ERROR DE CONEXIÓN**.

He estado tratando de buscar el error pero no lo encuentro.

```
public class GestionCambio extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText edtDatoVenta, edtDatoCompra;
    TextView ncambio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gestion_cambio);

        edtDatoVenta = findViewById(R.id.edtDatoVenta);
        edtDatoCompra = findViewById(R.id.edtDatoCompra);
        ncambio = findViewById(R.id.ncambio);

    }
        @Override
        public void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
            buscarproducto("http://www.ejemplo.com/mostrarCambio.php?codigo=1");
        }

    private void buscarproducto(String URL){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 1; i<response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        edtDatoCompra.setText(jsonObject.getString("compra"));
                        edtDatoVenta.setText(jsonObject.getString("venta"));
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR DE CONEXION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
            );
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);}
```

Éste es mi archivo PHP que genera el JSON. Cuando cargo la URL desde el navegador sí me carga los datos de la base de datos, pero lo pruebo en el celular me muestra el Toast **ERROR DE CONEXION**. La URL está bien indicada.

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$codigo = 1;
$consulta = "select compra, venta from tipo_cambio where idtc = '$codigo'";

$resultado = $conexion -> query($consulta);
while($fila = $resultado -> fetch_array()){
    $producto[] = array_map('utf8_encode',$fila);
}

echo json_encode($producto);
$resultado -> close();


?>
```

Comment: Puf, esto necesita una reforma profunda x) lo primero y más importante es, ¿qué permisos tiene la aplicación? ¿podrías compartir el manifest? Como mínimo necesitas `android.permission.INTERNET`.

Comment: Esta URL es muy muy muy peligrosa: `http://www.tcambio.byethost3.com/php/mostrarCambio.php?codigo=1` Ahora mismo cualquier usuario mal intencionado podría hacer estragos en tu servidor y en tus datos. Peor aún, hay bots que se dedican a buscar vulnerabilidades y a inyectar código dañino. Tienes que implementar consultas preparadas pero ya ya ya. Y mientras haces eso inhabilita el código. Sugiero que leas la respuesta de @OscarGarcia detenidamente y que leas aquí mismo y en la red sobre *Inyección SQL*. No puedes seguir programando así, es muy riesgoso.

Comment: ¿Podrías cambiar el toast a lo siguiente? `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. Tras eso dinos qué mensaje exacto sale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas, en primer lugar, es agregar los permisos necesarios en el [archivo de manifiesto](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) para que tu aplicación acceda a Internet.

Para agregar los permisos deberás agregar una etiqueta [`<uses-permission>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html) dentro de la etiqueta raíz [`<manifest>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` como la siguiente:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

Además, tu código sufre de los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Debes corregirlo haciendo uso de, por ejemplo, la función [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli.real-escape-string) de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Realizamos la consulta SQL escapando el contenido del código */
$consulta = "
  SELECT compra, venta
  FROM tipo_cambio
  WHERE idtc = '". $conexion->real_escape_string($_GET['codigo']) ."'
";
```

Además, no necesitas hacer uso de la función `utf8_encode()` en los datos obtenidos de la base de datos si éstos están ya en ella en utf8. Basta con cambiar el juego de caracteres de la conexión a MySQL para que todo esté al mismo nivel.

Si los campos no están en utf8 se puede hacer una conversión.

Tu código completo, mejorado con las propuestas planteadas, sería el siguiente:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

/* Indicamos el contenido que se va a generar */
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

/* No necesitamos usar utf8_encode si los datos de los campos están en UTF8 */
if ($conexion->set_charset('utf8') === false) {
  die(json_encode([
    'error' => true,
    'mensaje' => $conexion->error,
  ]));
}

/* Realizamos la consulta SQL escapando el contenido del código */
$consulta = "
  SELECT compra, venta
  FROM tipo_cambio
  WHERE idtc = '". $conexion->real_escape_string($_GET['codigo']) ."'
";

/* Realizamos la consulta SQL */
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

/* En caso de error enviamos el mensaje en JSON */
if ($resultado === false) {
  die(json_encode([
    'error' => true,
    'mensaje' => $conexion->error,
  ]));
}

/* Iniciamos el contenido de la variable */
$producto = [];
/* En vez de obtener datos duplicados, obtenemos únicamente los adecuados */
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    /* Agregamos el dato a la matriz */
    array_push($producto, $fila);
}

/* Enviamos al navegador o aplicación los datos */
echo json_encode($producto);

$resultado->close();
/* No es necesario ni recomendable cerrar PHP en scripts con solo código */
```